# Python script summary data separate by col

Tags: python, pivot

I want to count the data base on certain column follow the condition from another columns.

Raw data:

| Time | Lot | Error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1:00 | A | X |
| 2:00 | A | X |
| 2:12 | B | X |
| 2:30 | B | Y |
| 4:29 | C | Z |

Desired data show:

| Lot | Error | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 2 |
| B | X | 1 |
| B | Y | 1 |
| C | Z | 1 |

I tried using by "groupby" and "pivot" but it not work.

table = df.groupby(['Lot', 'Name']).sum('Name')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try count(), for both columns.

```
df.groupby(['Lot', 'Error']).count()
```

Output
Lot Error

```
A   X         2
B   X         1
    Y         1
C   Z         1
```

Also, if you need all the indexes that you have given, then you can do this:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Lot', 'Error']).count().reset_index()
df1.rename(columns={'Time': 'count'}, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
  Lot Error  count
0   A     X      2
1   B     X      1
2   B     Y      1
3   C     Z      1
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. That probably solved the problem.

Comment: @tungage If my answer helped you, then vote for it, set a check mark (it should turn green), which is below the upper and lower triangle.